# Can't pull oci array with ajax for use with ChartJs

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, chart.js, oracle-call-interface

I'm trying to use ChartJs and pull data from our Oracle database. I have followed the documentation as best I could and tried to adapt them for my oci output but I can't seem to get the data pulled.Here is my fetch array from data.php:

```
oci_execute($query);
$data = array();
while($row = oci_fetch_array($query, OCI_ASSOC)) {
  $data[] = $row;
}
print json_encode($data);
```

Which outputs this:

```
[{"DT":"01-FEB-18","SHIFTS":"FIRST","TOTAL":"6","IP":"5","DOMESTIC":"2","P_RICO":"3","EXPORTS":"1"},{"DT":"31-JAN-18","SHIFTS":"SECOND","TOTAL":"66","DOMESTIC":"49","P_RICO":"4","EXPORTS":"13"},{"DT":"31-JAN-18","SHIFTS":"FIRST","TOTAL":"55","DOMESTIC":"30","P_RICO":"1","EXPORTS":"24"},{"DT":"30-JAN-18","SHIFTS":"SECOND","TOTAL":"52","DOMESTIC":"34","P_RICO":"10","EXPORTS":"8"},{"DT":"30-JAN-18","SHIFTS":"FIRST","TOTAL":"69","DOMESTIC":"55","P_RICO":"2","EXPORTS":"12"},{"DT":"29-JAN-18","SHIFTS":"SECOND","TOTAL":"61","DOMESTIC":"41","P_RICO":"10","EXPORTS":"10"},{"DT":"29-JAN-18","SHIFTS":"FIRST","TOTAL":"48","DOMESTIC":"43","P_RICO":"2","EXPORTS":"3"},{"DT":"28-JAN-18","SHIFTS":"SECOND","TOTAL":"53","DOMESTIC":"44","P_RICO":"1","EXPORTS":"8"},{"DT":"28-JAN-18","SHIFTS":"FIRST","TOTAL":"53","DOMESTIC":"43","P_RICO":"3","EXPORTS":"7"}]
```

The PHP variables that I'm concerned with are DT, SHIFTS, and TOTAL. On my index.php I have this ajax call to get the variables:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "data.php",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var shifts = [];
            var total = [];
            var dt = [];

            for(var i in data) {
                shifts.push("Shift " + data[i].SHIFTS);
                total.push(data[i].TOTAL);
                dt.push(data[i].DT);
            }

            var chartdata = {
        labels: shifts,
                datasets : [
                    {
                        label: 'Shipments Complete',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: total
                    }
                ]
            };

            var ctx = $("#ships");

            var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartdata
            });
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

when I run index.php it just says that the variables are undefined.Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: So I just found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061726/how-to-make-a-graph-using-php-from-oracle. And I had already tried that anyway with no success.

Comment: Did you read the accepted answer of the question you linked to? Exactly as mentioned there, you have a case-sensitivity problem. E.g. use `data[i].SHIFTS`, `data[i].TOTAL`, `data[i].DT`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a graph using PHP from oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061726/how-to-make-a-graph-using-php-from-oracle)

Comment: Yes I had stated in my comment that I tried that and the variables are still undefined.

Comment: I have edited the ajax to reflect the current, case sensitive version.

Comment: [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v2z476c9/) shows your code works with uppercase keys, assuming your JSON `data` is as you provided. Your problem must be elsewhere. What's the actual error message and on what line of code does it occur?

Comment: I do not get an error message, only the chart does not populate and shows "Shift undefined"

Comment: I [updated the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v2z476c9/1/) with the rest of your code; a chart is displayed as expected. Verify that `data` really contains what you think it does.

Comment: Yeah I copied the data straight from the browser result so it's good. I don't really know how to debug ajax so do you know if this network result is an issue? That red line makes me think it's timing out or something similar. 
 https://i.imgur.com/4gousmI.png

Comment: The vertical red line in that image shows when the `load` event is fired, not any sort of error.  See the [DevTools reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#load).

Comment: So this is telling me that data.php is outputting correct right?  https://i.imgur.com/Dz51fYi.png

Comment: Looks like it (although that dataset is different to the one in your question). Use `console.log(shifts, total, dt);` immediately after the `for` loop to check the values of those variables.

Comment: Yeah I pared the query down to just the three variables that I needed. And in the console they are all coming up as undefined.

Comment: I feel foolish but I fixed it by adding `dataType: "json"`.

Comment: Good catch!  No need to feel foolish - I've lost count of the number of times I've spent _days_ trying to find the cause of a problem only for it to be the simplest thing :)  Next time you'll find this much earlier or avoid it completely; it's called experience!

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to help.