# PHP render stacked area chart of JSON dataset

Tags: php, chart.js

i want to chart (PHP) some info that i have on a BD oracle

I have this file to get the info in a JSON format:

## more data.php

```
<?php
 header('Content-Type: application/json');

 $conn = oci_connect('*****', '*****', 'HOSTNAME_FQDN:1521/ORACLE_SID');

 $graph=sprintf("select to_char(FECHA,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as Timestamp
    ,CPU
    ,BCPU
    ,BD_SCHEDULER
    ,UIO
    from sginfgbp.v_grafico_oem
    order by fecha desc");

 $parse=oci_parse($conn,$graph);
 oci_execute($parse);
 $data=array();
 while($row1 = oci_fetch_array($parse)){
 $data[]=$row1;

 }
 print json_encode($data);

?>
```

So, when i call http://SERVERNAME/data.php
i get a JSON dataset

**TIMESTAMP**   "03/07/2018 11:39:00"
    **CPU** "0"
    **BCPU**    "0"
    BD_SCHEDULER    "0"
    **UIO** "0"

**TIMESTAMP**   "03/07/2018 11:38:00"
    **CPU** "0"
    **BCPU**    "2"
    **BD_SCHEDULER**    "0"
    **UIO** "0" 
    ...
    ..
    ..
    .
    .

and so on.

How could i chart this info on a stacked area?

X axis = timestamp

Y axis = (value 1,color 1) , (value 2,color 2) , (value 3,color 3) , (value 4,color 4)

I am trying to "clone" the info on the thread:

[How to make a graph using PHP from oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061726/how-to-make-a-graph-using-php-from-oracle)

but i can not fix it.....

This is my bargraph.html (the URL that i finally call on the browser)

## more bargraph.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ChartJS - BarGraph</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #chart-container {
            width: 640px;
            height: auto;
        }
    </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="chart-container">
        <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
    </div>

    <!-- javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
 </body>
```

## more app.js

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/psm/admin/data.php",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        var timestamp = [];
        var cpu = [];
        var bcpu = [];
        var bd_scheduler = [];
        var uio = [];


        for(var i in data) {
            timestamp.push("TIMESTAMP " + data[i].TIMESTAMP);
            cpu.push(data[i].CPU);
            bcpu.push(data[i].BCPU);
            bd_scheduler.push(data[i].BD_SCHEDULER);
            uio.push(data[i].UIO);
        }

        var chartdata = {
            labels: timestamp,
            datasets : [
                {
                    label: 'Label ONE',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 170, 0.65)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(180, 190, 200, 0.75)',
                    hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(220, 200, 200, 1)',
                    hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(210, 200, 200, 1)',
                    data: cpu
                }
                             {
                    label: 'Label DOS',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                    hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                    hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                    data: bcpu
                }
            ]
        };

        var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

        var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'stackedArea',
            data: chartdata
        });
      },
      error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try setting the type as "`line`" and the "stacked" setting in the yAxes options:

```
scales: {
  yAxes: [{
    stacked: true,
  }]
},
```

In addition, you missed a comma "," between the 2 datasets objects.
Here's a [Codepen working example](https://codepen.io/natenorberg/pen/WwqRar) of a stackedArea chart.

If you could provide the JSON response from the server, we can check if the data is suitable to work with Chart.js.